# sqlite Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I made many attempts and did not find a ready answer
so...
the problem after the code is:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied.
```

The current statement uses 1, and there are 9 supplied.
I try with `WHERE H_Team={}` and  `curs.execute(sql_H.format(val))` and I get
**sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Barcelona**.
I try with `val = "'Barcelona'"` whit format {} and ok but why??

```py
import sqlite3 as lite

conn = lite.connect('F:\στοιχημα/apodoseis.db')
curs = conn.cursor()

val = "Barcelona" # (team_list[a][-1]) not yet...

sql_H = "SELECT H_Points FROM Master_Tamble WHERE H_Team= ? ORDER BY -H_Points"
curs.execute(sql_H, val)
points_H = curs.fetchone()
    
sql_A = "SELECT A_Points FROM Master_Tamble WHERE A_Team= ? ORDER BY -A_Points"
curs.execute(sql_A, val)
points_A = curs.fetchone()
    
print(max(points_H , points_A))
```

Comment: "I try with `WHERE H_Team={}` and `curs.execute(sql_H.format(val))` and I get" because that stringf formatting results in `where H_Team = Barcelona`, in SQL items which are unquoted are symbols or object names. In this context, the only thing that makes sense is a column.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try writing `curs.execute(sql_H, (val,))` and similar for sql_A. The second argument then becomes a tuple of 1 element. If you provide "Barcelona" as you're doing, it will use each letter as a value to insert. Hence the error it got 9 values but was only expecting 1.

Comment: That's the correct answer. [`execute` takes a sequence or mapping of parameters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) (either a tuple or a list should work, the list is usually more readable especially with a single value), it doesn't take a variable number of parameters.